# Appointment scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, schedule

Suppose you need to schedule meetings for a CEO.  There must be as many meetings (count, not duration) scheduled as possible.

The workday has a start time and end time.

There are certain blocks of time unavailable (lunch, etc.)

The input is a list of times.  The durations are either 30, 60, or 90 mins.

**My approach**

Represent the day as a boolean array.  The index is the time. Each array index represents 30 minutes.  So day[0] represents 9am and day[1] represents 9:30am.  day[1] = true means 9:30 is open and closed if false.

Have a counter variable to keep track of the current earliest free time.  For each time, iterate through the list of meetings and see if current free time + meeting duration is open.  Runtime is O(N*N).

**Flaw**

However, my method does not result in the highest possible number of meetings squeezed into a day.  For example, I have a 120 minute free block, and potential meetings of 90, 60, and 60 minutes.  My algorithm first iterates to the 90 minute meeting and schedules it, but there is a 30 minute free block wasted.  Better would be to fit both 60 minute meetings in there instead.

**Another idea**

Get all combinations of potential meetings with a total duration of no more than 90 minutes, and keep track of the the maximum number of meetings.  I believe this would have to be done via permutation and O(N*N!) for each free block.  So the total runtime of this is O(N * N * N!).

I would appreciate any feedback and alternative solutions.  Thanks!

Comment: In the general sense, this is called a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or a [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a new algorithm for you, that could be relatively simple to implement. First fit all the 90 min meetings, if some are left over, they would not fit. Now go through the 60 min meetings and place those. If you have some left over, find 90 min meeting with a 30 min window (there could not be 60 min window or the meeting would have fit) and replace it with 2 of the 60 min meetings. If there are still 60 min meetings left over, replace 2 consecutive 90 min meetings with 3 of 60 min. If there are still 60 min meetings left over, replace any 90 min meeting with 60 min meeting. Then go and place 30 min meetings to empty slots. If there are any left over, replace 90 min meetings with 3x 30 min. If there are more left over, replace 60 min meetings.

From what I know from the Knapsack problem is that there should be a polynomial solution and this seems to fit, so if this works, ... also if n is the number of free slots in schedule, this is capped at 6*n^2. It is independent of the number of meetings waiting to be scheduled.